# What is the explanation of president Gen. Yahya Khan's role in the general election of 1970?

Tags: pakistan, bangladesh

It is widely agreed upon that the 1970's election was a fair election. However, this 'fair' election became the cause of the split of Pakistan.

Firstly, president Yahya Khan's issued LFO(Legal Framework Order) put Sheikh Mujibur Rahman in an advantageous position in terms of seat distribution. Of a total of 300 seats, EP was assigned 162 seats. As a result, the election tilted in favor of Sheikh Mujibur Rahman from the outset.

Secondly, it is said that Yahya Khan tried to manipulate some seats in WP, but left EP unsupervised. As a result, Sheikh Mujibur Rahman was able to achieve a clean sweep. Of 300 seats, Sheikh Mujibur Rahman won 160 seats, and thus he became the sole contender for the PM of undivided Pakistan.

I have watched a number of youtube videos and read a number of books on the pre-1971 history of undivided Pakistan. Based on my research so far, the answer to this question is inconclusive. Pakistani writers blame Yahya Khan for this debacle, but they also don't pinpoint the reason. Bangladeshi writers project it as Sheikh Mujibur Rahman and Awami League's moral victory and the justification for the split of Pakistan.

What is the explanation of president Gen. Yahya Khan's role in the general election of 1970?

Comment: Why would he have needed to, if he's going to win without doing so? Under a multiparty parliamentary system a 55% majority is just as in control as a unanimous one.

Comment: "Pakistani writers blame Yahya Khan for this debacle. . . Bangladeshi writers project" It is possible that this is either a difference of opinion, or a rhetorical disagreement.  As far as I can tell your question (and the answers) cover the facts.  There may not be a reason why the various factions haven't reconciled themselves to the outcome.  There are Southerners in the US who still haven't reconciled themselves to the outcome of the Civil War; neither facts nor history will persuade them.

Comment: @MCW, I stated both of the opposing parties' views.

Comment: FWIW, IMO, this edit vastly improves the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: This answer was written in response to an earlier version of the question.)

There seems to be a source which addresses the issue.

The Wikipedia article on the [1970 Pakistani General Election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Pakistani_general_election) [mentions this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Pakistani_general_election#:%7E:text=Yahya%20Khan%20ignored%20reports%20that%20Sheikh%20Mujib%20planned%20to%20disregard%20the%20LFO%20and%20that%20India%20was%20increasingly%20interfering%20in%20East%20Pakistan.%5B10%5D%20Nor%20did%20he%20believe%20that%20the%20Awami%20League%20would%20actually%20sweep%20the%20elections%20in%20East%20Pakistan.%5B11%5D) (emphasis mine):

> Yahya Khan ignored reports that Sheikh Mujib planned to disregard the
> LFO and that India was increasingly interfering in East Pakistan.[10]
> ***Nor did he believe*** that the Awami League would actually sweep the elections in East Pakistan.[11]

This indicates that Yahya Khans' belief was that East Pakistan would not vote as a block, so he allowed the elections to proceed without interference.

This [article mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Pakistani_general_election#:%7E:text=Ian%20Talbot%20(1998).%20Pakistan%3A%20A%20Modern%20History.%20St.%20Martin%27s%20Press.%20p.%C2%A0193.%20ISBN%C2%A0978%2D0%2D312%2D21606%2D1.%20From%20November%201969%20until%20the%20announcement%20of%20the%20national%20election%20results%2C%20he%20discounted%20the%20possibility%20of%20an%20Awami%20League%20landslide%20in%20East%20Pakistan.) a book by professor [Ian Talbot](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/16996533.Ian_Talbot), and provides a direct quote from that book (emphasis mine):

> [Ian Talbot (1998). Pakistan: A Modern History. St. Martin's Press. p.
> 193. ISBN 978-0-312-21606-1.](https://books.google.com/books/about/Pakistan.html?id=ZBs0HdpKuaQC)

> > "From November 1969 until the
> > announcement of the national election results, ***he discounted the
> > possibility of an Awami League landslide in East Pakistan***."

He did not try to manipulate the election, since he did not see it necessary. He thought his party would win enough votes in the East to maintain power.

Comment: I agree. Yahya underestimated Mujib's popularity in East Pakistan. He assumed that there wouldn't be any clear winner between Mujib and Zulfikar Ali Bhutto, so a coalition government would be formed and he would act as the mediator, thereby retaining his seat of power as the president. But the election results were a slap on his face.